# Make attribute primary and foreign key in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key, ddl

How can I make an attribute a primary key within a table but also as a foreign key which references another table using sql in sql developer?
I know how to make it an attribute as a foreign key and a primary separate but not as a primary key as well as a foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly normal. For example:

```
create table employee (
  id number(6) primary key not null,
  name varchar2(50)
);

create table employee_desk (
  desk_id number(6) primary key not null, -- PK and FK!
  location varchar2(20),
  constraint fk1 foreign key (desk_id) references employee (id)
);
```

The column `desk_id` is the primary key of the table `employee_desk`, and also a foreign key that points to the table `employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of primary key with foreign key

```
 create table animals (id integer primary key);

  create table cats (
   id  integer   primary key
 , name varchar(100)  not null
 , constraint d_cats_animals_fk foreign key (id) references animals (id)
   );
```